# What is the relationship between Penetration, Protections and Power?

Tags: smite

When buying items, what is the relationship between power, protection and penetration, both physical and magical?

I am assuming that protection limits the amount of damage done through power, and that penetration nullifies protections, but is there a formula or easy way to work out how much penetration is needed to deal with protection, and how much power is taken away from protections? Does this differ from magical to physical?

Comment: is [This Link](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Damage) is helping you?

Comment: Why was the MOBA tag removed from this question? Smite is a MOBA.

Comment: @DrRDizzle On Arqade we try to avoid using unnecessary tags. While it's correct that Smite is a Moba, you should only use the [tag:moba] tag for questions that deal with Mobas in general. For specific game questions you should simply use the game-tag.

Comment: @Jutschge Fair enough, sorry for the rollback in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from [the Smite Wiki](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Damage)

Your Base Damage is Calculated as:

```
Base Damage + (Base Damage per lvl × God's lvl) + (100% of Physical Power OR 20% of Magical Power)
```

Then comes the Defence:

```
Damage = (100 × Unmitigated Damage)/(Protections + 100)
```

And the Penetration and Reduction:

```
Actual Defense = (Protection × (1-%Reduction) - Flat Reduction) × (1-%Pen) - Flat Pen
```

Where

- Percent Reduction. This will reduce a target's protection values by a percentage. For example, The Executioner will reduce a target's physical protection by 7% (per stack).
- Flat Reduction.. This will reduce a target's protection values by a specific amount. For example, Void Stone will reduce a target's magical protection by 15.
- Percent Penetration. This will reduce a target's protection values by a percentage. For example, Obsidian Shard will reduce a target's magical protection by 33%.
- Flat Penetration. This will reduce a target's protection values by a specific amount. For example, Warrior Tabi will reduce a target's physical protection by 15.

And to Answer your Question: There is no difference from magical and physical and there is no "simple" way :P

Comment: +1 for a great answer. Will mark as the answer unless something better comes along in the next few days.

Comment: So, it appears that `Actual Defense` can be negative. Assuming an example of 10 `Protection` and 1 stack from The Executioner, I get an `Actual Defense` of -18.819 with the other items you provided (ignoring defense types). Any idea how this impacts the amount of damage that's applied against the target hit? Are attacks doing an extra 19 points of damage in this case?